# flash.display.Graphics erasing

Tags: flash

Is there any way to erase a part of flash.display.Graphics canvas? Like

```
// var graphics:Graphics comes from somewhere
graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
graphics.endFill();
graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 0);
graphics.drawRect(50, 50, 150, 150);
graphics.endFill();
```

This produces just a red square (the last 3 calls are noop), and what i need is a transparent square hole in it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is easy, just draw both rectangles during the same fill:

```
// var graphics:Graphics comes from somewhere
graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

graphics.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 100); //I also made the inner rectangle smaller so it is a true hole
graphics.endFill();
```

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1EE3740D-F65C-43bf-9B12-74E34D7D1CBE.html for an explanation (the winding rules for "legacy" drawing API apply here.)